# How can I set some password length restrictions using python?

Tags: python, tkinter, passwords

Here is where I believe I would put the code for the restrictions

```
 def savePassword():
    os.system("Email.py")
    if txt.get() == txt1.get():
        # encode password for hashing
        hashedPassword = hashPassword(txt.get().encode("utf-8"))
        # insert masterpassword into database
        insert_password = """INSERT INTO masterpassword(password)
        VALUES(?) """
        cursor.execute(insert_password, [hashedPassword])

        sql_command = 'INSERT INTO details (email) VALUES(?) '  # Query
        email = txt3.get()
        cursor.execute(sql_command, [email])

        db.commit()

        passwordVault()


    else:
        lbl2.config(text="Passwords do not match")
```

i'd like it so that if the password does not reach a length requirement of say 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entry widget has `validate` and `validatecommand` that can do this job.

Here's an example code:

```
from tkinter import *

def check(ch):
    return len(ch) <= 7 or ch==''


root = Tk()
ent = Entry(root, show='*')
ent.config(validate='key', validatecommand=(root.register(check), "%P"))
ent.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

update:

```
from tkinter import *

def savePasswd():

    if len(ent.get())>7:
        label['text'] = 'saved'
        print("saved") # write save stmts here

    else:
        label['text']="Minimum length 7"


root = Tk()

label = Label(root)
label.pack()

ent = Entry(root, show='*')
ent.pack()

Button(root, text='save password', command=savePasswd).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm really looking for something that would be used in the if statement. So maybe in my case I would say if the length is more than 6 then Insert the password, if not then print what is currently "passwords do not match". I did try your method but it doesn't work for my code, it still just progresses to the next screen

Comment: I've edited my previous comment to try elaborate

Comment: @WilliamPearson I have made an edit check If that what you were looking for